# CodeIgniter Autocomplete for Eclipse causing problems

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, codeigniter-2

Followed this tutorial on getting autocomplete for CI to work with Eclipse http://taggedzi.com/articles/display/autocomplete-eclipse-codeigniter-2 - Worked fine.

Then tried to do this tutorial http://blog.pisyek.com/2011/03/create-a-simple-blog-using-codeigniter-2-0-part-1/ - Not so fine.

My test application would error at line 8 of the model (part 4). I worked out this was because $this->load was null, along with a set of other variables in the $this object.

I removed the added lines from the first tutorial and then my application worked fine, but I had no autocomplete.

How can I have both a working application and autocomplete for CI and Eclipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that the right solution is in this [tutorial](http://www.web-and-development.com/codeigniter-and-eclipse-autocomplete/).

Just need to put on some fake files within your project path.
It doesn't say anything for the model but should be the same, probably except your models.

Comment: Going to try it and will report back

Comment: Worked! I had a problem with the CI library not being included on my other dev setup correctly, but once I fixed that, worked as expected. Cheers! =] Bounty is yours!